# 'text()' from xpath returns error, invalid argument

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

Using `contains('text', 'some text')` works, but i want to check if it contains only what i'm inserting.. I found `contains(text()="some text")`, but it returns as a invalid argument.. Can you tell me what's the problem ?

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid number of arguments
```

Thanks in advance.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
html_source = session.get('any website')

passengers = html_source.html.xpath('*//div//h2[contains(text()="Passengers")]//ancestor::div[contains(@class, "wpb_wrapper")]')[1:-4]

for passenger in passengers:
    print(passenger.attrs)
```

Comment: Is BeautifulSoup an option or does js need to run on the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
r=sessions.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566739/text-from-xpath-returns-error-invalid-argument')r.html.xpath('//div[@id="question-header"]/h1[contains(text(),"from xpath returns")]')

question=r.html.xpath('//div[@id="question-header"]/h1[contains(text(),"from xpath returns")]')
```

["'text()' from xpath returns error, invalid argument"]
This is the output

See the example and change your xpath accordingly.I could have made it clearer had u given a proper url.The url I used is this page url and the output is Your Question title.Hope this helps.